# Change of graphical text interface, to completly text interface

Tags: networking, server, software-installation, ssh, headless

I'm working on some new project and I will use some PC with Ubuntu Server 14.04 on it as main server. Everything after install will be done through ssh. I already created virtual machine for editing few configs, but I figured out, that there will be a problem with entering passwords to textual graphic interfaces which are also shown in ssh session. This textual graphic interfaces are shown at postfix installation for example, and I couldn't paste the text to it using PuTTY. I'm talking about this type of interface:

[image: example: postfix installation]

Few months ago I was using Ubuntu Server 14.04 Minimal which had entire installation of postfix based on text, also choosing of mail configuration type was written with numbers from 1 to 5 (in order as listed above on the picture). Because I will install few packages in the future which use previously mentioned type of interface, I'd like to somehow avoid manually typing of passwords. Ubuntu Server Minimal had installation a little bit similar to this, except that it was needed to enter number of mail configuration type and other info after that:

[image: example: Ubuntu Server Minimal package installation]

I would really appreciate any suggestion on how to change interface type (at least for few installations I mentioned) or how to paste password into box of textual graphic interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reconfiguring a package with `dpkg-reconfigure`, you can choose between the *dialog* interface and a text-based *readline* interface on the command line using the `-f` or `--frontend` switch, e.g.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f readline tzdata
```

Alternatively, you can change the default frontend by reconfiguring the `debconf` package itself. From `man dpkg-reconfigure`:

```
   -ftype, --frontend=type
       Select the frontend to use. The default frontend can be permanently
       changed by:

        dpkg-reconfigure debconf

       Note that if you normally have debconf set to use the
       noninteractive frontend, dpkg-reconfigure will use the dialog
       frontend instead, so you actually get to reconfigure the package.
```

Comment: I changed frontend to readline with `dpkg-reconfigure debconf` and it works as expected. Do you maybe know what's the default value on Ubuntu Server 14.04 for questions in second step (possible values are critical, high, medium, low)?